# Phonegap plugins with emberjs

Tags: cordova, ember.js, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to both phonegap and emberjs.  I have an app working well with emberjs but now I'm trying to add some plugins. I use the commandline phonegap add plugin ...

The plugins install successfully but don't work when the app is compiled.

For instace org.apache.cordova.statusbar, which is supposed to prevent the statusbar from overlaping in ios7.

The plugin should work with the following code:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad(){
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
    }
    function onDeviceReady(){
        StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    }
</script>`
```

However when I build (locally) and deploy the statusbar continues to overlay.

Should I be using cordova rather than phonegap as I'm building locally? Is it possible that my use of ember is an issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello,

Can you make a test without referencing Ember.js ? You'll see no difference using Cordova rather than Phonegap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes I will make a test app, however, this app is a long way through development and I'd really like to get phonegap plugins working with ember.